# Access a file that requires cookies

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest, session-cookies, httpcookie

Actually my problem is I wanted to access a file stored on some xyz server. When I login through app and I access that file then a cookie is generated and I am allowed to access. Now my question is how can I access that file from browser if I can know the link by Packet Capturing of that app. Since I captured the previous packets so I know the previous cookies but that won't work in browser maybe because they are for 1request only. I don't know I am noob.
Please share your precious knowledge and help me in my problem.